# is .NET a framework like MFC or an API?

Tags: .net, visual-c++

If it is a framework, than can I use both MFC and .NET combined in C++ or must I pick one or the other?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Net is not just a framework, you can't use it from normal C++ like MFC or other C++ libraries. There is a special version of C++ called C++/CLI that can access both the .Net framework (and any .Net libraries) and also any normal C++ libraries. But C++/CLI is mostly for special purposes, like bridging between C++ library and C# application, it's usually not a good idea to use it as a general-purpose language.

So, is using .Net and MFC together possible? If you use C++/CLI, I think it is. Is it a good idea? No.

Answer (score 2):

.net is runtime actually like JVM. And .net FCL is framework class library provided to make programming for windows and web easier. Earlier we used MFC, WIN32 API for windows programming, now .net FCL provides much easier to use classes for the same.

Comment: if I have legacy code in MFC, how can I migrate it to .NET so I can utilize other people's .net classes and APIs?

Comment: Migration to .net in this case would mean complete re-writing of code. But that wont be an issue, as you wont be making something completely new. It will be only a bit time consuming but still an easy one.

Comment: Couple million lines of code to convert! Is there a macro way of doing it?

Comment: Better search google for it. But I bet, its impossible to make.

Answer (score 2):

.NET is a framework.

You can check out this thread:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/198090/mfc-vs.-.net